# How to make the this inside of jQuery event callbacks refer to the jQuery object by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope, this

So by default jQuery uses a HTML Dom Element as the calling object in a event callback

```
var el = $("#foo");

el.on("click", function()
{
    // this will output a div element
    console.log(this);
});
```

Is there a simple way to make it use the jQuery object as the calling function by default instead
so that "this" references the jQuery object and I don't have to wrap "this" in a jQuery constructor.

```
$("#foo").on("click", function()
{
    // this will instead output the jQuery object el declared above
    console.log(this);

    this.addClass("fee").find(".roo").remove();
});
```

I want to avoid creating variable names and just use "this" to refer to the jQuery object that added the listener.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own handler which calls a function bound to the jQuery collection:

```js
const onClick = (selector, callback) => {
  const jQueryCollection = $(selector);
  jQueryCollection.on('click', callback.bind(jQueryCollection));
};
onClick("#foo", function() {
  this.addClass("fee").find(".roo").remove();
});
```

```css
.fee {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">foo
</div>
```

Or, extend jQuery:

```js
$.fn.onClickWithThis = function(callback) {
  const jQueryCollection = $(this);
  jQueryCollection.on('click', callback.bind(jQueryCollection));
};
$("#foo").onClickWithThis(function() {
  this.addClass("fee").find(".roo").remove();
});
```

```css
.fee {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">foo
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use a preexisting option if possible, but since there doesn't seem to be one.

I overwrote the `on` function instead.

Most of the credit to CertainPerformance, but this solution works best since it overwrites the callback and works with the 4 available parameters that `on` can take.

```
(function ($)
{
    let originalOn = $.fn.on;

    $.fn.on = function(...args)
    {
        for(let key in args)
        {
            if(typeof(args[key]) == "function")
            {
                let originalCallback = args[key];

                args[key] = function(...args)
                {
                    originalCallback.bind($(this))(...args);
                }
            }
        }
        
        originalOn.bind(this)(...args);
    }
})($);
```